# Acquiring Stunts Multiple Times

Tags: dresden-files

In Dresden Files there are stunts that mention that you can take them multiple times, e.g. "High Quality Workspace". For stunts that don't state that, can they be taken multiple times?

In particular, the stunt "Resilient Self-Image" gives you a +2 mild, but doesn't say that can it can be taken multiple times. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that it's safe to assume that if one stunt specifically says it can be taken multiple times that stunts that don't specify it CAN'T be taken multiple times.  i'm not 100% sure this is spelled out in the book, but as the GM in my game this is the mindset that i would take if asked by one of my players.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that's your storyteller's call. Stunts are already a bit overpriced in the system, so that's unlikely going to be where the cheesiness comes in.